# How to detect remote connection experience settings?

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi, rdp

I'd like to disable my animations in WPF application when the user is connected remotely.

There is a good example of doing this here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jgoldb/2010/02/27/optimizing-visual-studio-2010-and-wpf-applications-for-remote-desktop/

I would however like to disable my animations only on lower performance profiles. My question is - how can I detect low quality connection over RDP or disabled "Menu and window animation" setting that user has chosen during connecting:

[image]

Comment: I think you call `SystemParametersInfo` passing `SPI_GETMENUFADE`